# When flushing a water heater, why is hot water coming out of the faucet when the cold water inlet valve and the T&P relief value are closed?

Tags: water-heater

Why is it that after I closed the cold water inlet to the water heater, I still got hot water from faucets inside the house?

If the cold water inlet is closed and the T&P relief valve is closed, it should create an effect as if a person put a finger on top of a straw. I'm confused why I'm still getting hot water from water faucets inside the house...

Comment: For a minute or two should get water out till pressure drops.  If still coming out a long time after, then the cold shutoff is not working.  Turn off at the main and see what happens.

Comment: @crip659 I'm certain the cold water inlet valve is working. I suspect I just need it to run the hot water longer (maybe 3 mins?). Once the pressure goes out, I should not be getting hot water from any faucet in the house. It's not possible to drain the water heater this way (by closing the cold water inlet valve and open the hot water faucet) correct?

Comment: There will be a brief pressurized supply if there's an expansion tank, as is common for newer installs.

Comment: Need to leave a hot water faucet open when draining so no vacuum.  Need the faucets open when filling to let out the air.  Assuming you know enough to turn off the power/gas to the tank before.

Comment: Some houses have multiple hot water systems in parallel -- seems odd to me but I have seen it, e.g. with an oil boiler and an electric hot water tank. In that situation you could have water, including possibly hot water, feeding from the "other" system.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the elevation of the open faucet relative to the hot water tank you might get some outflow simply due to gravity. Water might gurgle (technical term) out of the faucet but shouldn't be under pressure. If it is under pressure and continues turn the water off at the main shutoff.
Once you open the draincock on the tank and open a faucet on a higher floor that should stop.
Also cold water inlet valve may be leaking and in need repair/replacement.